# Microtype kerning in math mode (with mathdesign charter)

Tags: math-mode, microtype, mathdesign

In my document I find that some letters are to close to round brackets e.g. the small "p". Therefore I'm trying to add some extra space via microtype kerning, with little success so far. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[kerning]{microtype}
\UseMicrotypeSet[kerning]{allmath}
\SetExtraKerning{encoding={OMS,OML,U}, family={mdbch}}{p={1000,}}
\begin{document}
$$(p)$$
\end{document}
```

I suspect that again my font specification is probably just wrong, but I just can't figure out the correct one. I've skimmed through the fontname document and also tried `family={mdbchm}` however then I get an error message claiming it cannot find a kerning list or some such thing. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think `microtype` has no effect in math mode.

Comment: It should be possible though what else is the point of even having the presets allmath and basicmath?

Comment: So after further research/reading it seems the problem is that microtype doesn't have a configuration for charter in OML encoding by default and mathdesign doesn't provide one either? But surely one must exist for such a popular font and package?    Edit: Nope just checked and I get the same error when I try with computer modern math.

Comment: The presets `allmath/basicmath` are there for other features (eg., protrusion, expansion), which do work in math mode, too. I assume @egreg means that additional kerning has no effect in math mode, which seems to be a limitation of pdftex.